# Ubuntu won't play DVDs even after installing Codecs

Tags: codecs

I installed libdvdcss2, and it worked for a while, but now whenever I put in a DVD as of late, and try to play it, it'll tell me the DVD is encrypted and that it cannot be played... do note that all codecs are installed. What do I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

this is whats fixed mine when i was having same issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install w32codecs ubuntu-restricted-codecs vlc mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

Answer (score 2):

Just install

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Reboot.

Comment: He said it already installed `libdvdcss2`.

Comment: @enzotib, Grayson didn't make it clear whether he ran the second line (`install-css.sh`). There *is* a possibility he has been using non-CSS-encrypted DVDs.

Comment: A lot of people forget the second part. They just download ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: It says it needs "X-NAUTILUS-DESKTOP" protocol source