# Ubuntu 13.04 Not displaying DVD Content

Tags: 13.04, dvd, cd

I am new user for Ubuntu. I have updated my OS from Ubuntu 12.04 to (12.10 and now) 13.04. I have a DVD of movies, which works fine in Windows 7, and I am able play the movies, and can see the contents. But when I try that DVD in my Ubuntu, I am getting Blank "DVD-R disk" under device, and when I click on it, it just displays option to burn the disk, not displaying the content, I am not able to see the movies which are there in DVD. Help me resolve the issue

[image: Blank CD/DVD drive image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete reinstall:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/vlc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install w32codecs ubuntu-restricted-codecs 
sudo apt-get -y vlc mozilla-plugin-vlc
sudo apt-get -y install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4
sudo sh /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
sudo apt-get -y install regionset
sudo regionset
rm -R ~/.dvdcss/
```

Please read [Linux Set DVD Region Code](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-switch-change-alter-dvd-region-code/). You may also have to reboot...

Please refer also to these other similar questions:

- [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500)
- [Unable to play DVDs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115009)
- [Ubuntu won't play DVDs even after installing Codecs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53169)
- [How to install libdvdcss?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151471)
- [What plugin do i need to get DVD use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71109)
- [Why does DVD playback still not work after installing libdvdcss2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185587)
- [DVDs not playing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300731)
- [Why does my optical drive not play commercial dvds?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247502)
- [Problem with DVDs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90841)

For your information, as explained on Wikipedia article about [`libdvdcss`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libdvdcss#Distribution), Ubuntu does not provide `libdvdcss` to respect [Digital Millennium Copyright Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act).

Comment: I have tried this, but still it doesn't work... :(

Comment: I have added more stuff to install in my answer. Please try what I have added. Have you read the other answers? Have you Have you rebooted? Do you have an error message? `dmsg`? What is the title of your DVD? Does your DVD embeds [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) protection? (it should be mentioned somewhere on the DVD) **Is your DVD reader able to read any other DVD? (using Ubuntu 13.04)**

Comment: I have tried everything what you have suggested, but still it shows me like "Blank DVD-R disk". when I click on it, the title something like "Data disc (12 Jul 13)".

Comment: I have again competed my answer, please redo all the steps. Please, check your DVD reader using others DVDs: maybe your DVD reader (driver) is not (yet) functional on Ubuntu 13.04...

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg libxine1-ffmpeg gxine mencoder libdvdread4 totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 mpg321

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

sources:
http://www.itworld.com/software/354185/enable-dvd-playback-and-install-multimedia-codecs-ubuntu-1304

http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/tweaksthings-to-do-after-install-of.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same blank disk problem on self burned data dvd disks, but noticed, that I can see the files in it if  remounting manually, by doing:

```
umount /dev/sr0
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /home/krister/disk
```

Afterwards Ubuntu automatic mounting works too **for this dvd only**, but I haven't checked if this retains over reboot.

- Could you guys fix this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'quirk' that may still exist so I'm putting it out here even though it's not directly germane to more recent 64 bit Linux distros. My 32 bit Debian 8 distro on a Toshiba Satellite laptop requires I use the right-click Eject function on the previously inserted disk in order to recognize the file structure of a newly inserted video disk, but oddly, not software disks such as Plop (disk based USB/media bootloader for computers whose bios doesn't recognize bootable usb sticks on startup).

Hope this helps someone. Took me some time to figure it out.